# Updating timestamps with #update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I have list of ids that I want to update their property the `updated_at` field in the database doesn't seem to change, here is what I mean :

```
ids = [2,4,51,124,33]
MyObj.where(:id => ids).update_all(:closed => true)
```

After this update is executed `updated_at` field doesn't change. However when I enter rails console with `rails c` and do this :

```
obj = MyObj.find(2)
obj.closed = false;
obj.save!
```

After this statement `updated_at` field changes value. Why is this? I'm relying on this `updated_at` field in my app as I'm listening to the updates and doing whole app flow when this happens?

**Edit**

I just found out from `dax` answer that :

```
Timestamps

Note that ActiveRecord will not update the timestamp fields (updated_at/updated_on) when using update_all().
```

I don't want to be updating one record at a time, is there a way around this? without resorting to sql level?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`#update_all` [does not instantiate models](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all).

As such, it does not trigger callbacks nor validations - and timestamp update is made in a callback.

Edit about edit :

If you want to keep the "one query to rule them all", you can update updated_at as well as `:closed` :

```
MyObj.where(:id => ids).update_all(closed: true, updated_at: DateTime.now)
```

But be aware validations are still not run.

Comment: +1 for 'one query to rule them all' -and this is a better answer :)

Comment: thank you for the answer olivier. I've also thought of this I just hope there is more elegant solution. thanks I'm gonna go for this for now.

Comment: I think `Time.now` in that case is more appropriated

Comment: Do not use DateTime.now, use DateTime.current which will use the apps default time zone, which is UTC+00 by default. DateTime.now uses system's time zone.

Comment: @blushrt It doesn't matter in this case. Active Record is smart enough these days to convert Time.now to the DB time zone in queries like this one. In other situations (especially when you deal with dates instead of times) you *do* need to be careful about time zones.

Answer (score 1):

Updates all, This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. Values passed to update_all will not go through ActiveRecord's type-casting behavior. It should receive only values that can be passed as-is to the SQL database.

As such, it does not trigger callbacks nor validations - and timestamp update is made in a callback.update_at is a call back  for reference http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all

Answer (score 0):

> Timestamps
>
> Note that ActiveRecord will not update the timestamp fields (updated_at/updated_on) when using update_all().

source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all

Comment: is there a way around this?

Comment: basically just create your own `update` column and update that along with whatever else you're updating

Comment: If I understood correctly, Gandalf want to touch updated_at, not to avoid touching it. Am I right, Gandalf ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I did make a gist that outlines how to roll it yourself.

https://gist.github.com/timm-oh/9b702a15f61a5dd20d5814b607dc411d

It's a super simple implementation just to get the job done.
If you feel like there is room for improvement please comment on the gist :)